# Bounded linear function

Tags: functional-analysis

$F$ is a non-zero bounded linear functional on $C[0,1]$ and it satisfies $$F(fg)=F(f)F(g)$$ for all $f,g$ in $C[0,1]$. The norm used here is the sup norm, $\|f\|=\underset{x\in [0,1]}{\sup}|f(x)|$.

In the first part of the question I need to show that if $f$ is nonnegative in $C[0,1]$, then $F$ is nonnegative too, i.e. $F(f)\geq 0$.

The Weierstrass Approximation Theorem is assumed in the question. I don't know how is the theorem relevant or probably I don't need it at all in the first part.

2nd part is that $h(x)=x$, so $h$ is the identity function. Show that $0\leq F(h)\leq 1$. Is this something to do with $F(1)$?

3rd part is to show $F(f)=f(a)$ where $a=F(h)$ for all $f\in C[0,1]$

Do I have to use the Weierstrass Thm at all?

Comment: Hint: What is $F(1)$ ?

Comment: I worked out that $F(1)$ must be 1.

Comment: For the second part, since $F$ is bounded linear, there exists a constant $c$ such that $|F(h)|\leq c\|h\| =c$ since $h(x)=x$. But how do I proceed from here...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Take $\sqrt{f}$ then $F(f)=F(\sqrt{f})^2 \geq 0.$ As you can see $F(1)=F(1)^2 \Rightarrow $ either $F(1)=1$ or $F(1)=0$ but $F(1)=0$ implies $F=0$. So take $F(1)=1$ then if $h$ is identity function it will imply $1-h \geq 0 \Rightarrow 0 \leq F(h)\leq F(1)=1.$

Comment: Do you mean by $F(f)=F(\sqrt{f} \sqrt{f})=F(\sqrt{f})F(\sqrt{f})=(F(\sqrt{f}))^2 \geq 0$? so simple haha. Thanks

Comment: Yes , right. $f\geq 0$ so you can consider $\sqrt{f}$.

Comment: Got it! you are using the fact that $F$ is linear to prove the result. Thanks man,

Answer (score 1):

For the third one, we have $F(p(x))=p(F(x))=p(a)$ for any polynomial $p(x)\in C[0, 1]$, since $F:C[0,1]\to \mathbb{R}$ is a ring homomorphism. Now, for any $f\in C[0, 1]$, there exists a sequence $\{p_{n}(x)\}$ of polynomials which uniformly converges to $f(x)$. Now continuity of $F$ (equivalent to boundedness of $F$) implies that $F(f) = \lim F(p_{n}(x)) = \lim p_{n}(a) = f(a)$.

Comment: Is this where the theorem needs to be assumed? Is the $x$ in your $F(x)$ a function? Because I thought the argument for $F$ is a function

Comment: I think so. As @kevin did, we don't need Weierstrass theorem for 1 and 2.

Comment: Your $a$ here is $F(h)$ where the $h$ is the identity function in part 2 right?

Comment: Yes it is. (4 more characters to finish comment)

Comment: One last question Lee, may I know which property of ring homomorphism have you applied in your working above?

Comment: I used definition of ring homomorphism. For example, we should have $F(x^{3}+2x+7) = F(x^{3})+F(2x)+F(7) = F(x)^{3}+F(2)F(x)+F(7) = F(x)^{3}+2F(x)+7$ by linearity and multiplicativity of $F$ (which is definition of ring homomorphism). We also need $F(1)=1$ in here, too.